# DropzoneJS change height

Tags: jquery, css, dropzone.js

I want to change the height of [DropzoneJS](http://www.dropzonejs.com/) but it keeped fixed on 1060 x 312 pixels.

I tried to change the CSS class but it didn't worked. Also when I try with jQuery to change the CSS, nothing happens. In Google Chrome Developer Tools, if you changes the height and width, it automatically changes back to 1060x312.

Any solutions?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

put this css in your page like..

```
<style>
.dropzone {
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
min-height: 0px !important;
}   
</style>
```

Comment: When I apply this style my dropzone wont change after uploading file. It seems that the uploaded file drops outside of dropzone space. Also when there are multiple files the height of the dropzone wont change. Is there any way that I can reduce dropzone initial height and it would remain flexible?